# force interface up despite no carrier using ethtool/nmcli/iproute2?

Tags: linux, networking, networkmanager, ethernet

I'm interested in knowing if it's at all possible in Linux or Unix to force a interface in a "up" state despite there not being a carrier, meaning

```
# ip link
enp3s0f0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
```

This is a fiber optic interface with the TX connection unplugged, RX is however plugged in and data is sending towards the interface.

`tcpdump` reports nothing on the interface which I assume is because the kernel is not registring anything on this interface as it's `NO-CARRIER`.

I've tried using both `ethtool` and `nmcli` to turn off `AUTONEG` and other link discovery features:

```
nmcli> print all
===============================================================================
                       Connection profile details (Fiber1)
===============================================================================
connection.type:                        802-3-ethernet
connection.interface-name:              enp3s0f0
connection.autoconnect:                 yes
connection.metered:                     unknown
connection.lldp:                        disable
connection.mdns:                        -1 (default)
connection.llmnr:                       -1 (default)
connection.wait-device-timeout:         -1
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
802-3-ethernet.port:                    --
802-3-ethernet.speed:                   1000
802-3-ethernet.duplex:                  half
802-3-ethernet.auto-negotiate:          no
802-3-ethernet.mtu:                     1500
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ipv4.method:                            disabled
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ipv6.method:                            disabled
```

My understanding is that these settings should disabled all nessecary auto-detect features from being performed and hand over a manual-handling of the interface and it's parameters.

But even after running *(and `ip link set dev enp3s0f0 up`)*:

```
[Torxed@machine torxed]# nmcli con up id Fiber1
Connection successfully activated (D-Bus active path: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2)
```

The interface reports as:

```
enp3s0f0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
```

A weird artifact is this:

```
# nmcli
...
enp3s0f0: connected to Fiber1
        "Intel X710"
        ethernet (i40e), 40:A6:B7:00:00:01, hw, port 40a6b72000001, mtu 1500
```

I'm not sure why `nmcli` reports it as `connected` as Linux does not.

I've also looked into the driver a bit, and it seems like the `i40e`-driver doesn't have any calls to the kernel API [netif_carrier_on()](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/networking/API-netif-carrier-on.html) in the `i40e_ethtool.c` section. And there doesn't seem to be a implemented way in [ethtool](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/network/ethtool/) either to force such a thing, at least not a standardized parameter. `ethtool` does allow for setting privately exposed flags via `--set-priv-flags`. But the Intel driver doesn't have a flag to handle this scenario. So unless someone blows my mind here I'm probably forced to modify the driver at this stage.

**End goal**: get `tcpdump` to see `ICMP request` over the fiber without `TX` being connected on the machine in question, responses are not expected on either end.

Hardware: Two port Intel X710 with standard multi-mode fiber LC connectors *(TX disconnected)*.